# Bootstrap customization not working in angular 7

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to customize bootstrap 4 theme in angular 7,

i have installed bootstrap,

in my angular .json i have

```
 "styles": [
                "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
                "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                "src/styles.scss"
            ],
```

style.scss is my custom scss class,

inside style.scss

im trying to change colour of warning theme

```
    @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

   $theme-colors: ( "warning": #0074d9, "danger": #ff4136 );
```

i have a button with btn-warning class , im trying to change btn-warning color. But not working

style.scss is rendering in my view but, button color is not changing.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: add your custom scss file in assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried moving the import of bootstrap.scss down  in my style.scss like :

```
$theme-colors: ( "warning": yellow, "danger": #ff4136, "customcolor": red);

@import "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your style array, you are importing bootstrap.min.css and in style.scss you are imported bootstrap.scss. why you are importing this two different css files? this two files will override each other.

Comment: please refer the link i followed: https://medium.com/@manivel45/configuring-angular-7-project-with-sass-bootstrap-and-angular-material-design-69b0f033dc04

Comment: In this tutorial i didn't found style.scss added with this  @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";

Comment: remove  @import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"; from style.scss and then try once

Comment: i tried removing the import statement, and it stopped working, import statement is mandatory.